# update textview from inside of thread?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-activity

There is an int value that continuously get updated inside a thread and I want to show the value in a textview but i m unable to use findviewbyid inside of thread ?

How to refer to that textview from inside that thread and update it accordingly?

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.raj.testview;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class TextChange implements Runnable 
{
    public void run()
    {
        TextView tv=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv);

        for(int i=0;i<10000;i++)
        {
            tv.setText(String.valueOf(i));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please add some code to your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change UI elements from a non-UI thread. Try using [runOnUiThread](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)).

```
runOnUiThread(new Runnable(){
    @Override
    public void run(){
       // change UI elements here
    }
});
```